# Sentence correctness with "in"

Tags: prepositions

Is it correct to say "in" if you want to say you are talking without moving your lips? Or would you say this somehow differently?

> She is looking at my lips trying to find moves ***in*** them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is not grammatically correct, Try this: She is looking at my lips trying to find (detect) any movement in them

Comment: Why is it incorrect? What do you mean by "detect"?

Comment: ...........'find moves'.......is not correct, so I changed it for movement, which is correct.  I also added detect as an optional alternative  to find (that's why it's in parentheses)

Comment: Okay, I only didn't understand why movement not moves, move can be noun too, right?